# C# Manipulate PowerPoint animation is paused when there is no window focus. Need a solution

Tags: c#, vba, windows, powerpoint, ms-office

I'm developing a C# project, the program needs to let the PPT switch to the next page, at the same time, my program needs to put a window on top of the PPT window for drawing, which leads to the focus can't be given to the PowerPoint, resulting in the animation pause problem of the projection window, what is the solution for this? Thanks!

I currently manipulate PowerPoint with the following code:

```cs
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application pptApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("PowerPoint.Application");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation pptDoc = pptApp.ActivePresentation;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.SlideShowWindowpptWindow = pptDoc.SlideShowWindow;

pptWindow.View.Next();
```

I would like to be able to have PowerPoint play animations correctly without giving it focus. This would be best solved through C# code, either by tweaking the PowerPoint settings, or by helping me edit a macro and merge it into the program.

Comment: Add more details, like what type of project you're creating - WinForms, console, or are you doing this from within PP. Also add screeshots explaining the focus issue to help us understand better.